# Firebase Analytics does not work in my app

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

I migrated my GCM project to Firebase, until then, everything is working correctly, but the analytics today showed nothing, does not work.

I deleted my old package that was `com.mypackage.gcm` to `com.mypackage` in the Firebase console and I don't know if that was the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The package name of your app has to be the same as in `google-services.json` file that you should redownload from firebase console(Project Settings page). Have you updated the `google-services.json` file with the new package name?

Comment: Yes. I've updated the google-services.json, all other Firebase features works correctly but not analytics.

Answer (score 5):

Please enable debug logging and provide the logcat output. It is not possible to diagnose a problem without any information.

You can enable Firebase Analytics debug logs with this adb commands:

> ```
> adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
> adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
> adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
> ```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log

Comment: I understand look at this - [logcat-output](http://pastebin.com/h8QcgqEx)

Comment: There are no errors in the logcat so the data will be uploaded within 1 hour of logging. You can follow the instruction in your logcat on how to enable debug mode that will upload the data within 10 seconds if you like. I assume your app is "br.lgfelicio". Go to firebase console > settings and check that your App ID matches the one you use in the app: "1:1033684201634:android:ac9807da202a819a" (printed in your logcat). If the one printed in setting doesn't match the one in the logcat you are  looking at the console for another project.

Comment: Hello thanks for your help, I looked at the app ID is the same. Good think really the problem is to delete the old app developer who was in google console. I will create another new project, which will be with another new project **notifications** will work for older versions of my app?

Comment: I don't understand your question at the end of your comment. What is the good think?

Comment: Can you also send screen shot of the Firebase Analytics console chart? Make sure you only include the chart, not account details in the screen shot.

Comment: My question was: If I create another project. Notifications will work in older versions of my app?

Comment: I think so but please make sure you test this. Creating new project should fix the issue with Firebase Analytics.

Comment: Thank you @djabi for saving my time :)

Answer (score 3):

I wasted a **lot** of time before I realized that my VPN was interfering somehow.  In order to get debugview working again, I had to log off the VPN, quit the emulator, re-open the emulator, and then turn debugging back on using

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <packagename>
```

And presto, finally, debug events show up in the console DebugView.